# Enumerate Function Output:

Tags: python

Please let me know what  is the error here:

```
numbers = [3,11,17,25,28,30,35,32,46,65,97,72,45,22,14,150]
def fizz_buzz(numbers):

    for i,num in enumerate(numbers,start=10):
        if num%3==0:
            numbers[i] = 'fizz'
        if num%5==0:
            numbers[i]= 'buzz'
        if num%3==0 and num%5==0:
            numbers[i]= 'fizzbuzz'
        else:
            continue

    return numbers

print(fizz_buzz(numbers))
```

Output:

```
    numbers[i]= 'buzz'
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: `start=10` is the culprit, but it is hard to help without knowing what you want to achieve.

Comment: Here I just want the normal output that enumerate provide such as: [(10,3),(11,11),(12,17),(13,25),(14,28), and so on]. But  I am getting like                                             [3, 11, 17, 25, 28, 30, 35, 32, 46, 65, 'fizz', 72, 45, 'buzz', 14, 'fizzbuzz'] . That i don't understand..It should come with the index as well as with the change value(n case)

Answer (score 0):

You start with index 10

```
    for i,num in enumerate(numbers,start=10):
```

So you are accessing the array `numbers[16]` in the 7th iteration which is out of range.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. Here (start  = 10) means the output list will start from  index 10 instead of 0.Right?

Comment: @SoumyaRanjanSahu yes.

Comment: So yes, the issue is I am not getting the output as I expected like: [(10,3),(11,11)...so on.Please help me out

Comment: @SoumyaRanjanSahu take a look at my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your array has 16 elements and since array indexing is 0 based, the last element will be numbers[15] and not numbers[16] and your programs is trying to execute numbers[16] so it is getting index out of range error.

Give a check to your function like below :

```
numbers = [3,11,17,25,28,30,35,32,46,65,97,72,45,22,14,150]
def fizz_buzz(numbers):

    for i,num in enumerate(numbers,start=10):
        if i < len(numbers):
            if num%3==0:
                numbers[i] = 'fizz'
            if num%5==0:
                numbers[i]= 'buzz'
            if num%3==0 and num%5==0:
                numbers[i]= 'fizzbuzz'
            else:
                continue

    return numbers

print(fizz_buzz(numbers))
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks it works. However, I expect the below output:                                                   [(10,3),(11,11),(12,17),(13,25),(14,28), and so on].Could you please help to achieve above output

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the following output:

```
[(10,3),(11,11),(12,17),(13,25),(14,28), and so on].
```

It can be the following:

```
numbers = [3,11,17,25,28,30,35,32,46,65,97,72,45,22,14,150]

def fizz_buzz(numbers):
    result = []

    for i,num in enumerate(numbers):
        if num%3==0 and num%5==0:
            result.append((i+10, 'fizzbuzz'))
        elif num%3==0:
            result.append((i+10, 'fizz'))
        elif num%5==0:
            result.append((i+10, 'buzz'))
        else:
            result.append((i+10, num))

    return result

print(fizz_buzz(numbers))
# [(10, 'fizz'), (11, 11), (12, 17), (13, 'buzz'), (14, 28), (15, 'fizzbuzz'), (16, 'buzz'), (17, 32), (18, 46), (19, 'buzz'), (20, 97), (21, 'fizz'), (22, 'fizzbuzz'), (23, 22), (24, 14), (25, 'fizzbuzz')]
```

If you want the answer without fizz/buzz words, do the following:

```
numbers = [3,11,17,25,28,30,35,32,46,65,97,72,45,22,14,150]
numbers = [(i+10, num) for i, num in enumerate(numbers)]
print(numbers)
# [(10, 3), (11, 11), (12, 17), (13, 25), (14, 28), (15, 30), (16, 35), (17, 32), (18, 46), (19, 65), (20, 97), (21, 72), (22, 45), (23, 22), (24, 14), (25, 150)]
```